# how to consume files in order when using Apache Camel SFTP

Tags: java, apache-camel, sftp, spring-camel, camel-ftp

I am using Apache Camel to handle files in a SFTP directory.The directory will receive many files in the same time.What can I do to control camel consumes the file in order?
For example,directory *my_directory*  will receive file file1,file2,file3,file4 in the same time. I want camel to consume then in the order of file1-file2-file3-file4.

Answer (score 0):

Have you taken a look at the option `preSort`?

Answer (score 0):

From this [section](https://camel.apache.org/components/latest/file-component.html#_sorting_using_sortby), you could sort the file by file name with `sortBy` option

> This will sort by file name
>
> `sortBy=file:name`

P.S. you may find many useful info from File component for FTP/SFTP component